# SQL Update Skipping duplicates

Tags: sql, sql-server, distinct

Table 1 looks like the following.

```
ID  SIZE    TYPE      SERIAL
1    4      W-meter1  123456
2    5      W-meter2  123456
3    4      W-meter   585858
4    4      W-Meter   398574
```

As you can see. Items 1 and 2 both have the same Serial Number. I have an innerjoin update statement that will update the UniqueID on these devices based on linking their serial number to the list.

What I would like to do. Is modify by hand the items with duplicate serial numbers and scripted update the ones that are unique. Im presuming I have to reference the distinct command here somewhere buy not sure.

This is my update statement as is. Pretty simple and straight forward.

```
update UM00400

Set um00400.umEquipmentID = tb2.MIUNo

from UM00400 tb1


inner join AA_Meters tb2 on
tb1.umSerialNumber = tb2.Old_Serial_Num
where tb1.umSerialNumber  <> tb2.New_Serial_Num
```

Answer (score 0):

```
;WITH CTE
AS
(
    SELECT * , rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY SERIAL ORDER BY SERIAL)
    FROM UM00400
)
UPDATE CTE
SET CTE.umEquipmentID = tb2.MIUNo
inner join AA_Meters tb2 
on CTE.umSerialNumber = tb2.Old_Serial_Num
where tb1.umSerialNumber  <> tb2.New_Serial_Num
AND CTE.rn = 1
```

This will update the 1st record of multiple records with the same SERIAL.

Comment: What is the with CTE ?

Comment: Never mind. Since I saw it posted twice. A little googling does a lot even on something that simple. However I didn't return the results you did. Now for testing..

Comment: CTE is common table expression read here to learn more about it http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/265371/Common-Table-Expressions-CTE-in-SQL-SERVER-2008

Answer (score 0):

If i understand your question correctly below query will help you out :

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
// getting those serial numbers which are not duplicated

SELECT umSerialNumber,COUNT(umSerialNumber) as CountOfSerialNumber
FROM UM00400 
GROUP BY umSerialNumber
HAVING COUNT(umSerialNumber) = 1
)

UPDATE A SET A.umEquipmentID = C.MIUNo
FROM UM00400 A 
INNER JOIN CTE B ON A.umSerialNumber = B.umSerialNumber
INNER JOIN AA_Meters C ON A.umSerialNumber = C.Old_Serial_Num
```

Comment: What is the ;with CTE as ?

Comment: I beleive something Is wrong here. Once I reach the Update A SET portion, The system is telling me it cannot find 'A' and honestly I don't see it defined either. I have never used CTE and this is also a sql 2003 box, Not 2008 so I am unsure if CTE is fully supported or not . @wizavi

Comment: I changed the with CTE AS to with A as and it eliminated the Update A error however now umequipmentid is in error because it wasn't selected into A I presume.

Comment: Please check it now ... i forgot to give alias name to main table - UM00400 which is to be updated.

Comment: closer. Your innerjoin is incorrect. i have to leave but will try to work out the rest of it.  FYI Innerjoin CTE B on A is where the error presents itself.